# Casting to string versus calling ToString

Tags: c#

```
object obj = "Hello";
string str1 = (string)obj;
string str2 = obj.ToString();
```

What is the difference between `(string)obj` and `obj.ToString()`?

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to Guillaume, this has nothing to do with boxing. String is a reference type - there's no need for boxing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting vs Converting an object toString, when object really is a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170756/casting-vs-converting-an-object-tostring-when-object-really-is-a-string)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

- `(string)obj` [casts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) `obj` into a `string`. `obj` must already be a `string` for this to succeed.
- `obj.ToString()` gets a string representation of `obj` by calling the [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method. Which is `obj` itself when `obj` is a `string`. This (should) never throw(s) an exception (unless `obj` happens to be `null`, obviously).

So in your specific case, both are equivalent.

Note that `string` is a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) (as opposed to a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)). As such, it inherits from object and no [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) ever occurs.

Comment: One thing to note is that obj, str1 and str2 all reference the same object. So Explicitly casting an object that is a string into a string, will return the objectreference itself.

Comment: An object doesn't necessarily have to be a string for it to succeed. It also works if there is an explicit conversion operator defined.

Comment: You are obviously right about the conversion operator. But for the sake of non confusion, I'll keep it in the comments. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: if obj is null then ToString() will throw a exception.

Comment: Rodolfo is correct - if `obj` is null (even if it is a null string) then `obj.ToString()` will throw an exception. Instead, you can use `obj?.ToString()` which will produce the same effect and not throw an exception if `obj` is null

Answer (score 18):

If its any help, you could use the 'as' operator which is similar to the cast but returns null instead of an exception on any conversion failure.

```
string str3 = obj as string;
```

Comment: Good point, [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-as-operator-keyword/) is for ones who want to read more about it.

Answer (score 9):

At the most basic level:

`(string)obj` will attempt to cast `obj` to a `string` and will fail if there's no valid conversion.

`obj.ToString()` will return a `string` that the designer of `obj` has decided represents that object. By default it returns the class name of `obj`.

Answer (score 2):

(string)obj cast the object and will fail if obj is not null and not a string.

obj.ToString() converts obj to a string (even if it is not a string), it will fail is obj is null as it's a method call.

Answer (score 1):

ToString() is object class method (the main parent class in .net) which can be overloaded in your class which inherits from object class even if you didn't inherited from it.

(string) is casting which can be implemented in the class it self, the string class so you don't have ability on it.