# SSIS Getting Exception When Accessing Int Variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I am trying to create a script that will generate folders that I need on the fly.

The script takes a `FolderName` and `OrderID` variable to generate the folder names to create.  I Added them to the Read Only variables for the script.

[image]

Everything works fine with the `FolderName`, it's only when I try to access the `OrderID` variable that things blow up.  I get the nasty Exception error below.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        //  Output File Expression
        //     "" + @[User::FolderName]+"\\Folder_"+ (DT_WSTR,20) @[User::T1_ID]  +"\\SalesOrderHeader_T1_"+ (DT_WSTR,20) @[User::T1_ID]+ ".txt"

        String folderName = (string)Dts.Variables["User::FolderName"].Value;
        String OrderIDStr = (string)Dts.Variables["User::OrderID"].Value;
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(OrderIDStr, "OrderID Var");

        folderName = string.Concat(folderName, "\\Folder_");
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(folderName, "Folder Name");

        try
        {
            // Determine whether the directory exists.
            if (Directory.Exists(folderName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That path exists already.");
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("That path exists already.", "WARNING");
                return;
            }

            // Try to create the directory.
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
                Console.WriteLine("The directory was created successfully at {0}.", Directory.GetCreationTime(folderName));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
        finally { }
    }
```

I'm setting the value to `1` at the package level, and I'm casting it to String, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

[image]

The text gets cut off in the box, here is everything:

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at system.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object
>       obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke
>       (Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo 
>       culture) at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>       bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] 
>       modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Comment: It is an integer in the database and a string in your code : String OrderIDStr = (string)Dts.Variables["User::OrderID"].Value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.ToString()` method instead of casting `(string)`

```
String OrderIDStr = Dts.Variables["User::OrderID"].Value.ToString();
```

Based on this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit-numeric-conversions-table), explicit casting is not allowed from `int` to `string`.

**References**

- [Casting to string versus calling ToString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565100/casting-to-string-versus-calling-tostring)
- [Explicit numeric conversions table (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit-numeric-conversions-table)
- [Casting and type conversions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)

Comment: Ugh, damnit!  I tried: String OrderIDStr = Dts.Variables["User::OrderID"].ToString();