# Difference between .ToString and "as string" in C#

Tags: c#, string, tostring

What is the difference between using the two following statements? It appears to me that the first "as string" is a type cast, while the second ToString is an actual call to a method that converts the input to a string? Just looking for some insight if any.

```
Page.Theme = Session["SessionTheme"] as string;
Page.Theme = Session["SessionTheme"].ToString();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting vs Converting an object toString, when object really is a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170756/casting-vs-converting-an-object-tostring-when-object-really-is-a-string)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If `Session["SessionTheme"]` is not a `string`, `as string` will return `null`.

`.ToString()` will try to convert any other type to string by calling the object's `ToString()` method. For most built-in types this will return the object converted to a string, but for custom types without a specific `.ToString()` method, it will return the name of the type of the object.

```
object o1 = "somestring";
object o2 = 1;
object o3 = new object();
object o4 = null;

string s = o1 as string;  // returns "somestring"
string s = o1.ToString(); // returns "somestring"
string s = o2 as string;  // returns null
string s = o2.ToString(); // returns "1"
string s = o3 as string;  // returns null
string s = o3.ToString(); // returns "System.Object"
string s = o4 as string;  // returns null
string s = o4.ToString(); // throws NullReferenceException
```

Another important thing to keep in mind is that if the object is `null`, calling `.ToString()` will throw an exception, but `as string` will simply return `null`.

Comment: `ToString()` will 'try to convert any other type to string'? With most built-in types, yes. With your own custom stuff in Session, say a complex User object, all depends whether you've overriden `ToString()` and how you've implemented it in your class. If not implemented it returns the type info string.

Comment: Yes, of course. But the point here is to illustrate the difference between ToString() and "as string". If I want to provide a complete answer, it would be 2 pages long

Comment: My comment explains it. That's not 2 pages long. It's about being *accurate*.

Comment: I added a few lines to my answer

Comment: @Wim: being accurate can sometimes confuse the OP. Which doesn't mean accuracy is not a good thing, but sometimes it's better to keep an answer short

Comment: appreciate both your guys comments :) Thanks!

Comment: what would you say about this `string s =o2?.ToString()`

Answer (score 14):

The `as` keyword will basically check whether the object `is` an instance of the type, using MSIL opcode `isinst` under the hood. If it is, it returns the reference to the object, else a null reference.

It *does* not, as many say, attempt to perform a cast as such - which implies some kind of exception handling. Not so.

`ToString()`, simply calls the object's `ToString()` method, either a custom one implemented by the class (which for most in-built types performs a conversion to string) - or if none provided, the base class `object`'s one, returning type info.

Answer (score 10):

I'm extending Philippe Leybaert's accepted answer a bit because while I have found resources comparing three of these, I've never found an explanation that compares all four.

- `(string)obj`
- `obj as string`
- `obj.ToString()`
- `Convert.ToString(obj)`

```
object o1 = "somestring";
object o2 = 1;
object o3 = new object();
object o4 = null;

Console.WriteLine((string)o1);           // returns "somestring"
Console.WriteLine(o1 as string);         // returns "somestring"
Console.WriteLine(o1.ToString());        // returns "somestring"
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(o1)); // returns "somestring"
Console.WriteLine((string)o2);           // throws System.InvalidCastException
Console.WriteLine(o2 as string);         // returns null
Console.WriteLine(o2.ToString());        // returns "1"
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(o2)); // returns "1"
Console.WriteLine((string)o3);           // throws System.InvalidCastException
Console.WriteLine(o3 as string);         // returns null
Console.WriteLine(o3.ToString());        // returns "System.Object"
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(o3)); // returns "System.Object"
Console.WriteLine((string)o4);           // returns null
Console.WriteLine(o4 as string);         // returns null
Console.WriteLine(o4.ToString());        // throws System.NullReferenceException
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(o4)); // returns string.Empty
```

From these results we can see that `(string)obj` and `obj as string` behave the same way as each other when `obj` is a string or null; otherwise `(string)obj` will throw an invalid cast exception and `obj as string` will just return null. `obj.ToString()`
and `Convert.ToString(obj)` also behave the same way as each other except when `obj` is null, in which case `obj.ToString()` will throw a null reference exception and `Convert.ToString(obj)` will return an empty string.

So here are my recommendations:

- `(string)obj` works best if you want to throw exceptions for types that can't be assigned to a string variable
- `obj as string` works best if you don't want to throw any exceptions and also don't want string representations of non-strings
- `obj.ToString()` works best if you want to throw exceptions for null
- `Convert.ToString(obj)` works best if you don't want to throw any exceptions and want string representations of non-strings

EDIT: I've discovered that `Convert.ToString()` actually treats `null` differently depending on the overload, so it actually matters that the variable was declared as an `object` in this example. If you call `Convert.ToString()` on a `string` variable that's `null` then it will return `null` instead of `string.Empty`.

Answer (score 7):

```
Page.Theme = Session["SessionTheme"] as string;
```

tries to cast to a string

whereas

```
Page.Theme = Session["SessionTheme"].ToString();
```

calls the `ToString()` method, which can be anything really. This method doesn't cast, it should return a string representation of this object.

Answer (score 4):

First of all "**any-object as string**" and "**any-object.ToString()**" are completely different things in terms of their respective context.

```
string str = any-object as string;
```

1) This will cast any-object as string type and if any-object is not castable to string then this statement will return null without throwing any exception.
 2) This is a compiler-service.
 3) This works pretty much well for any other type other than string, ex: you can do it as any-object as Employee, where Employee is a class defined in your library.

```
string str = any-object.ToString();
```

1) This will call ToString() of any-object from type-defination. Since System.Object defines ToString() method any class in .Net framework has ToString() method available for over-riding. The programmer will over-ride the ToString() in any-object class or struct defination and will write the code that return suitable string representation of any-object according to responsibility and role played by any-object.
 2) Like you can define a class Employee and over-ride ToString() method which may return Employee object's string representation as "FIRSTNAME - LASTNAME, EMP-CDOE" .

**Note that the programmer has control over ToString() in this case and it has got nothing to do with casting or type-conversion.**

Answer (score 4):

To confuse the matter further, C# 6.0 has introduced the [null-conditional operator](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6). So now this can also be written as:

```
Page.Theme = Session["SessionTheme"]?.ToString();
```

Which will return either null or the result from ToString() without throwing an exception.

Comment: While this is useful, not sure how it directly answers the question of the difference between `as string` and `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `as string` check is the object is a string. If it isn't a null it returned.

The call to `ToString()` will indeed call the `ToString()` method on the object.

Comment: It doesn't attempt to cast. It checks whether the class is an instance of the specified type and returns the reference if so, else null.

Answer (score 1):

The first one returns the class as a string if the class is a string or derived from a string (returns null if unsuccessful).

The second invokes the ToString() method on the class.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best way of writing the code above is to do the following:

```
if (Session["SessionTheme"] != null)
{
    Page.Theme = Session["SessionTheme"].ToString();
}
```

That way you're almost certain that it won't cast a NullReferenceException.