# Read boolean values from DB?

Tags: c#, .net, sqldatareader

In C#, using SqlDataReader, is there a way to read a boolean value from the DB?

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    destPath = reader["destination_path"].ToString();
    destFile = reader["destination_file"].ToString();
    createDir = reader["create_directory"].ToString();
    deleteExisting = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["delete_existing"]);
    skipIFolderDate = reader["skipifolderdate"].ToString();
    useTempFile = reader["useTempFile"].ToString();
    password = reader["password"].ToString();
}
```

In the code above, delete_existing is always a 1 or 0 in the DB. I read on MSDN that Convert.ToBoolean() does not accept a 1 or 0 as valid input. It only accepts true or false. Is there an alternative way to convert a DB value to a bool? Or do I need to do this outside of the SqlDataReader?

Also, I can not change the DB values, so please no answers saying, "Change the DB values from 1's and 0's to true's and false's."

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If the type of `delete_existing` is a sqlserver 'bit' type, you can do :

```
var i = reader.GetOrdinal("delete_existing"); // Get the field position
deleteExisting = reader.GetBoolean(i);
```

or (but it will crash if `delete_existing` can be `DBNull`)

```
deleteExisting = (bool)reader["delete_existing"];
```

or better, this onebelow is `DBNull` proof and returns **false** if the column is `DBNull`

```
deleteExisting = reader["delete_existing"] as bool? ?? false;
```

Otherwise if the database type is `int` :

```
deleteExisting = (reader["delete_existing"] as int? == 1) ? true : false;
```

or if it is a `varchar`

```
deleteExisting = (reader["delete_existing"] as string == "1") ? true : false;
```

Comment: @Laurent Hmm... I would rather go with the third option because someone could add a column to the table and then, obviously, the app would break. However, can you explain what exactly is going on in the second option? I am confused by the "as bool? ?? false;" specifically the 3 ?'s...

Comment: 3rd solution: I'm trying to cast reader["delete_existing"] to a nullable bool (bool?). This way, the cast fails and returns null if the field contains DBNull.Value. Because I prefer to get false instead, I am using the ?? which transform a null to any value (ie: null ?? 45 = 45). I uses this a lot.

Comment: 2nd solution: I'm doing a direct cast to a bool. This one will throw an exception if the value is not a boolean type. For example, if it is DBNull.Value. That's why it should be used with not null bit database field. Just choose the one that fits your needs ^^ What is the database type of delete_existing btw ?

Comment: @Laurent What is the difference if I use a .ToString()? For example... deleteExisting = (reader["delete_existing"].ToString() == "1") ? true : false;

Comment: I'm afraid reader["delete_existing"].ToString() will return "True" or "False" instead of 1 or 0 if the underlying database type is bit. Otherwise, if it is a varchar or an int, deleteExisting = reader["delete_existing"].ToString() = "1"; is OK

Comment: @Laurent, Would you agree that as string is always a better option than .ToString()? Or is that debatable? Possibly another SO question...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099900/difference-between-tostring-and-as-string-in-c This answered my question above. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: it will crash if delete_existing can be DBNull - gave me clue why my code was not working. Thanks

Comment: Did I really wrote `? true : false;` ? This is totally redundant! XD

Answer (score 3):

Casting works:
myVar = (bool)dataReader["myColumn"];

Comment: That works if the value returned is actually a bit. If someone lazily selected a 1 or 0 as an integer that cast will fail.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
deleteExisting = (reader["delete_existing"] as int?) == 1;
```

Boolean is probably the easist type to convert something to. Here's the 'Y', 'N' version:

```
deleteExisting = string.Equals(reader["delete_existing"] as string, "Y", StringComparision.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CASE in SELECT and want to use GetBoolean then use CAST to change the column to bit before reading.

For eg:

```
SELECT CAST((CASE WHEN [Condition] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bit) FROM Table_Name
```

then you can use

```
reader.GetBoolean(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
deleteExisting = reader.GetBoolean(reader["delete_existing"]);
```

Comment: this statement returns an error. I assume it is because the GetBoolean function wants an Int passed in, and reader["delete_existing"] is not an int yet...

Comment: Try casting it? It should auto cast to an int I believe but you can try explicitly doing reader.GetBoolean((int)reader["delete_existing"]);

Comment: I'm sorry, in GetBoolean(x), x is not a value to convert to bool, but rather an integer that is the position of the field to read in the datareader.

Comment: GetBoolean expects an ordinal = index of the column to get.