# A little bit of string cast

Tags: c#, sql

**Update:**

---

When a database returns a value through the scalar, it will always be an `object`.  So when the value is returned you should have a preconceived notion of what the type will be.  Why would you use `ToString();` when you you have a `SELECT` which passes two parameters.

As if it doesn't exist it will always throw a `null`.  So in my refactor I believed the `as` would be the proper approach.  As `ToString()` will throw an error --- So what form of `cast` is it comparable to?

---

I've got some code I'm maintaining, but in apart of my refactor I came across a `ToString()` attached to an `ExecuteScalar`.  My question would be, does the usage of `ToString()` equate to:

```
(string)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Or would it represent this:

```
command.ExecuteScalar() as string;
```

Obviously the `as string` would fail gracefully, where the `cast (string)` would actually fall into an `InvalidCastException`.  So when you call:

```
command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Which method of `casting` is it attempting to do?

Comment: Keep in mind that ExecuteScalar could return null.

Comment: What does ExecuteScalar return? (System.Object.) Is there documentation on System.Object.ToString() anywhere on the internet? (Yes.) Let alone testing your own code, what research did you do?

Comment: @Greg, Why have you have not consider Convert.ToString()?

Comment: [This][1] answer may help you to understand the difference:



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170756/casting-vs-converting-an-object-tostring-when-object-really-is-a-string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean either of those - it simply means calling `ToString()` on whatever the value is.

In particular, if the value is *not* a string, it will convert it to a string anyway - whereas `string` would fail with `InvalidCastException` and the `as` would return null.

So for example:

```
object x = 10;
string a = x.ToString(); // "10"
string b = x as string; // null
string c = (string) x; // Bang
```

Of course, `ToString()` can still throw an exception too - most obviously if the target of the call is a `null` reference.

Personally, I would suggest using a cast if you know what the result type should be - although the result of `ExecuteScalar` is more *commonly* a numeric value (e.g. a count) rather than a string.

Yes, that means an exception will be thrown if you're wrong - but if your query isn't doing what it's meant to anyway, then stopping due to an exception may well be better than going ahead with a bogus view of the world. (See [my blog post on casting vs `as`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions/) for more on this attitude.)

Comment: With the ExecuteScalar, you need to compensate for DbNull as well via `var x = blah.ExecuteScalar();` `var y = x == DbNull.Value ? null : (int) x;` right?

Comment: In your example, which of those options would the run-time choose if we used the code `String.Concat(x,"")` which in theory would both give us a string and avoid a null reference in all cases?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: Quite possibly, depending on context.

Comment: @xDaevax: I'm not sure what you mean by "which of those options would the runtime choose" - it would call `string.Concat(object, object)` and would call `ToString` on each non-null argument.

Comment: I definitely have to compensate for DBNull in a lot of our code, so I thought it was worth mentioning :)  When you say context, are you saying it could be different depending on RDBMS or different depending on something else?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: I'm saying that if the query is *actually* performing a count, for example, it might never be null.

Comment: I see.  I did not know that was the behavior of the Concat method.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 7):

Neither, because `Object.ToString()` will returns you a string representation of the object. Regardless whether the query returns a `varchar` or `int`.

Answer (score 1):

If `command.ExecuteScalar()` returns `null` then it would be something like `null.ToString()` which will break your production code.

also `(string)command.ExecuteScalar()` can break your code.

I would suggest to use below line

```
var result = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;
if(result != null)
{
  //your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about it for a bit.

When you do command.ExecuteScalar() you get back and object in a lot of cases based on the provider you get an int.

What happens is the order of operations triggers

- Command.ExecuteScalar() gets and object back.
- We are assuming he is an int for the excercise we get that int back.
- To String gets called which is defined in the int32 object itself.
- You get back the string that was determined inside.

For the most part toString is not meant to throw an exception if no one has implemented in the chain you just get the object type back which is the implementation on the object.

With that said in the case of the int it would probably be the one above. Note if execute scalar returns null to string will error out since null is not an object.

Hope that helps.

P.S. If you tell me the object type of ExecuteScalar i can give you a better answer.