# What happens when calling Object.ToString when the actual type is String

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say we have the folowing code.

```
var foo = "I am a string";
Object obj = foo;
var bar = obj.ToString();
```

What is actually happening?

1. Cast the obj to a string and then calls the ToString Method?
2. Calls the ToString method on obj which is the override of string without casting?
3. Something else?

Witch one is better to do?

1. `var bar = obj.ToString();`
2. `var bar = (string)obj;`

Comment: You are asking 2 questions in a one topic.

Comment: `ToString` is overridden by `string` so to your first question, it's the 3rd option, no casting happens but `string.ToString` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) From the open-source dotnet sources at https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/String.cs:

```
// Returns this string.
public override String ToString() {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
    return this;
}
```

The override just returns `this`.

2) I would just use `var bar = foo;` instead of the cast or the `.ToString()`. If you only have an object, then yes `.ToString()` is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

ToString is a method defined in the Object class, which is then inherited in every class in the entire framework.

The ToString method in the String class has been overwritten with an implementation that simply returns itself. So there is no overhead in calling ToString() on a String-object.

So, I don't think there's anything to worry about.

Also, I would go with the first option. It's more readable, and you should always get a result, no matter what type "obj" is.

Comment: You don't need to bet when the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,2758) is available. Also, your ALWAYS may be a bit too strong - you *might* get a `NullReferenceException` instead of a result.

Comment: You are right. I updated my answer.

Comment: Just lookin in decompile there oyu can see one line of code in the string implementation:                return this;

Comment: True. I looked up the source as well, as Damien_The_Unbeliever suggested. I updated my answer once more.

Answer (score 0):

> What is actually happening?

Your code can actually be something like this

```
var foo = new String("I am a string".ToCharArray());
Object obj = foo;
var bar = obj.ToString();
```

C# `string` keyword is an alias to `String` class.
The `ToString` method that you called simply uses polymorphism mechanism to call proper `ToString` implementation. As you may know `string` is a reference type and a child class of `Object`

> Witch one is better to do?

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1170788/1095390) answer.

> The two are intended for different purposes. The ToString method of
>   any object is supposed to return a string representation of that
>   object. Casting is quite different, and the 'as' key word performs a
>   conditional cast, as has been said. The 'as' key word basically says
>   "get me a reference of this type to that object if that object is this
>   type" while ToString says "get me a string representation of that
>   object". The result may be the same in some cases but the two should
>   never be considered interchangeable because, as I said, they exist for
>   different purposes. If your intention is to cast then you should
>   always use a cast, NOT ToString.